# Tag helpers on external URLs without protocol

Tags: php, phalcon, volt

I am attempting to use volt tag helpers such as `stylesheet_link` to link to an external URL without protocol prefix.

Example usage without protocol proves to be problem free:

```
{{ stylesheet_link('http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}
```

Generates

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

.

However, whenever the protocol prefix is obmitted (ie/ `//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css`):

```
{{ stylesheet_link('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}
```

Generates incorrect URL:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="[SITE_PREFIX]//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

Is it due to my incorrect usage? or is this an existing bug with volt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try specifying that it's not local, [see the docs](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Tag.html).

```
{{ stylesheet_link('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css', false) }}
```